# Home button of ipod touch 4g (32 gb) giving problem

Tags: ipod-touch, accessibility

i have a ipod touch 4th generation 32gb which is around 1 year old. i dint drop it even once but still the home button is not working properly.
it doesnt respond even if i press it hard sometimes. i am using the assistive touch home button but it takes away some part of my screen and is troublesome at times..
can anyone please tell me what the problem is and how can i recitfy it.
i had jail broken the device once. now i have updated to version 6.1 from itunes and no jailbreak.
if i Recalibrate my device’s Home Button by following [this](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2011/12/22/recalibrate-home-button-responsive/) method, the button respond better for just a little while

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a relative known problem with iPhone 4(s) and iPod Touches.

If it's still under warranty, take it back to the store and they should fixed it for you (or replace the device).

Comment: oh. but its not under warranty and more over its a gift from U.S. i stay in india.
so is there a way to get it repaired in india?(authnetically, i dont want to go to any electrician)
im ready to pay.

Comment: This is a known issue. You can fix this at many locations - in my neighbourhood there are plenty 3rd party shops around that will fix this for a dollar or 20.